# Excel Complex Conditional

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Ok so I did this in LibreOffice but now I have to duplicate it to excel for my Pay Roll department since they use excel. So I am having to figure out how to convert the formulas to Excel. This is only 1 of two totaling formulas that did not convert when I saved it as Excel format.
I have the following sheet called DailyReport

[image]

I am currently calculating Column M with =SUMPRODUCT(A2:A200=A2, G2:G200)

Then on a secondary sheet I have the following second sheet WeeklyReport 
[image]

Now what I want to do is if WeeklyReport Column A2 == DailyReport Column A then take the date in DailyReport Column B and test it to fall in the date range in WeeklyReport Column B and Column C with =IF(AND(DailyReport.B2>=B2,DailyReport.B2<=C2),1, 0) and if that is true add the Total Daily Hours to the total in WeeklyReports Column D from DailyReports Column M

I hope this is clear enough if not please let me know what else I can do to make my question more clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to me it sounds like:

You want a sum of all hours, for a specific employee (defined by the A column value weekly report), in between the dates specified (also defined by weekly report, b & c column) - and you want the end result to be in WeeklyReport column D and all of it to relate to the same row as the result?

sumproduct will do the trick. I am renaming your sheets to DR and WR for my sanity's sake.

```
=sumproduct((DR!G$2:G$200)*(DR!A$2:A$200=A2)*(DR!B$2:B$200>=B2)*(DR!B$2:B$200<C2))
```

Now, if you want a new daily report sheet every day it gets a bit trickier to do with formulas alone, you should then have a macro to store the "current" value and add the "new" value, or for simplicity's sake create more columns (one for each working day) and duplicate the formula to all daily columns, or have as many named dailyreports as there are working days in a week and increase the formula to check multiple sheets. I would add columns - least amount of work and the dumbest solution often proves the most resilient.

Did that help in any way?

Comment: That is what I am after however when I input it and replace DR with my sheet names it results in 0 every time no matter how many times the employee shows up in Column A. This is what I was facing when I made my post :P any more input would be great. I would have preferred like you said and take the dumbest solution however it does not meet their 'needs' HAHAHAHAHA gotta love billing/payroll/accounting and all their rules.
Any more input you have would be great.

Comment: Well, sumproduct is an unforgiving formula, and that it throws a 0 shows that the syntax is correct. It just can't find any records that matches all criterias. I hate to ask this, but are you sure the names are spelled right both places and that the dates in the dailyreport are actually between the ones on the weeklyreport? (Edit: also that the formula is located in D2 on WR. )When we have this error sorted out, I would recommend you try to make a tiny macro with an "update" button so they can add the total to the week.

Comment: Yes the name in column A is selected from a list mapped to a named range DataList.

Comment: And the dates? Are they date-formatted properly? (you can test this by simply writing in a cell in dr "= c3+1". it should show the next day's date. check this for both wr and dr.

Comment: Yes it does add a day to the date. So they are formatted properly.

Comment: Ok it works, for whatever reason Excel was deleting the end of the formula. I recreated the file and it worked. Thanks marking this as the approved answer!